# How to execute IOS app in background

Tags: ios, iphone, audio-streaming, sonos

I am currently working on streaming app which stream iPhone song to other hardware over TCP network, hence the sound will come out of a hardware that is connected to the iPhone by wifi.
  It's working fine when the app is foreground but in the background the app will be terminated after some time. 
  There is one app "Sonos" which is working in background. I don't know how it streaming in background to hardware, Is there any different approach used?

Could you tell me the solution that will accept by apple?
Thanks in advance........

Answer (score 3):

Apple supports `backgroundmode` for certain operations/task. Check the screenshot.Select your target and go to `capabilities` tab there you can find this options.Select the task/operation for which your want background support.

[image]

Comment: To complement this answer, you might want to use `Background fetch` as Background Mode unless you are using `AirPlay`.